# Как определить одновременное нажатие двух клавиш case Key.LeftCtrl + Key.S?

Tags: c#, wpf

Работает только определение нажатия одной клавиши case Key.LeftCtrl:

```
<Window
KeyDown="KeyDownMy"
    >
```

```
void KeyDownMy(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        //case Key.LeftCtrl & Key.S:
        case Key.LeftCtrl:
            e.Handled = true;
            NodeSave(null, null);
            break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотите привязать <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> к команде сохранения? Это делается не так.

Вы в окне, в котором эта команда должна работать, привязываете комбинацию клавиш к команде.

Если ваша команда доступна в VM (то есть в `DataContext`), вы делаете так:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

---

Если ваша команда определена где-то в другом месте, понадобится более сложный код. В этом случае имеет смысл привязаться к `ApplicationCommands.Save`:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="Save" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Теперь нужно на `ApplicationCommands.Save` привязать вашу имплемнетацию сохранения. Вы определяете два метода:

```
void SaveCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true; // или False, в зависимости от логики
}

void SaveExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NodeSave(null, null);
}
```

и привязываетесь так:

```
var saveBinding = new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Save, SaveExecute, SaveCanExecute);
CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(System.Windows.Window), saveBinding);
```

Не забудьте, что сохранение — не дело окна или другой View-компоненты, вынесите это в VM или даже в модель. (Вы ведь используете MVVM, да?)

---

Не забывайте, что вы можете к этой же команде привязать и пункт меню, и кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

```
 bool leftctrl= false;
    bool s = false;

    private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LeftCtrl )
        {
            leftctrl= true;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            s= true;
        }

        if (leftctrl && s)
        {
            MessaeBox.Show("одновременное нажатие");
        }
    }


    private void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LeftCtrl )
        {
            leftctrl = false;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            s = false;
        }
    }
```